# Bracket highlighting in cream

Tags: vim

I would like to know how to highlight matching brackets in cream. The matching bracket only flashes once when I type its pair.

Thanks!
--nikita.utiu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work by default.

See `:help pi_paren`

It is possible it is not displayed when you have your cursor over a `}` because there is no Highlight group "MatchParen" defined in your color scheme.

To check, type `:highlight` and check that is a line with MatchParen defined.

If not you can try to change your colorscheme or add the following line in your .vimrc or .gvimrc :
`:hi MatchParen ctermbg=blue guibg=lightblue`

Answer (score 0):

For me Xavier T.'s method didn't work.

Cream FAQs suggest to create a file called `cream-user.vim` in your `$HOME/.cream` directory. And in that file you put

```
if exists("g:loaded_matchparen")
unlet g:loaded_matchparen
endif
runtime plugin/matchparen.vim
DoMatchParen
```

This worked perfectly fine for me.